# Which is more expensive (in $): database memory or processing power?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, hosting

This is a fairly abstract question, I hope it is within bounds.

I'm about 5 months into my coding career in web development.  I've found that there's often a tension between CPU and storage resources.  Put simply, you can use less of one and more of the other, or vice versa (then throw in the speed consideration).  I'm now getting to the point of deploying my first app for production, so this balance is now a matter of real dollars and cents.  The thing is this: I really don't have *any* idea what kind of balance I should be looking for.

Here's some salient examples that might illuminate the balance to be struck in different case scenarios.

**Background**

I am working on an app that does alot of diffs between text.  Users will call on pages that contain diffs displayed in html.  A lot.

**First Case**

Should I run a diff each time a page is displayed, or should I run the diff once, store it, and call it each time a page is displayed?

**Second Case**

I have coded up an algorithm that summarises diffs.  It's about 110 lines of code, and it uses 4 or 5 loops and subloops.  Again, should I run this once and store the results, so that they can be called on later, or should I just run the algorithm each time a page is displayed?

Would also love to hear your views on the best tools to use to quantify the balance.

Comment: This is an impossible question to answer with any certainty. Deploy your app on a test server and run loads of common use-cases. See how much space you use vs. how much CPU time and do the math. My gut feeling says that CPU time is more expensive than storage, but gut feelings are no substitute for profiling.

Comment: Sounds like it will be CPU bound ie it will use more CPU than any other resource. If you can, reduce the number of nested loops you have to do and number of loops you perform in general. Also, I would say only generate a diff when necessary, for example, when text is changed. Finally, storage is pretty cheap. From Amazon S3 it's 12.5 cents per GB. Your mileage may vary with CPU and Memory costs

Comment: Why is it hard to write "a lot" as two distinct words?

Comment: Do not worry about the answer to this question before you have written an implementation. Write an implementation and then test it. Or, after you have written an implementation put memcache in front of it.

Comment: I encourage you to also read Greg Smith's book, PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance, as it's widely recommended for people making scaling choices and tuning their servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difficult to answer without testing it out but you might want to answer these questions:

1) How expensive is the diff operation? Run a test or compute the complexity. If diff operation is on really large files or rapidly changing files, you might want to modify the algorithm. Storing diffs doesn't seem like a great solution if the files are large, change little or change rapidly over time.

2) How many times would you need to generate the same diff with the same files and is there a time bound associated with this? 
- If the same diff is generated over and over again in a short span of time, you might want to cache it and not write it to a database. If the diff is accessed sporadically over time (Few days, months), you might want to store it that is after analyzing 1 above.

You might benchmark using costs on Amazon Web Services. Again you have choices there. You could just use a single EC2 instance for everything or split the workflow against RDS, EC2 and S3 and then analyze the cost. Depends on what level of scale you desire.

Comment: Thanks for this - all of these considerations are relevant.  Great starting point for research.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is basically should you cache or should you not cache. Caching is in most cases advisable but you should have a limit on your cache size. When the cache is full the least recent items accessed should be removed from the cache to make place for recently accessed items.

A small amount of cache can often greatly reduce CPU load.

You may wish to take a look at [memcache](https://addons.heroku.com/memcache)

Memcache implements for you the automatical removal of old items in favour of new ones. All you have to do is when you generate data put it in the cache and when you need data first check to see if memcache still has it if not then generate it.

Comment: To put it differently, scale up the cache as much as you can without buying more hardware. Sometimes you can't, and have to buy more, but at least it's a first approximation.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to store the cache in DB-tables, not in memory. If the entries  are referenced a lot, they *will* be in memory (in disk buffers). The advantage of this approach is that the diffs will be competing for a place in core with the other DB tables, which is always smarter than pre-allocating (and managing) XXX bytes of memory.

An addtional advantage is that maintaining {hitcount,date of access, ...} for the cache entries is relatively easy, and its management can all be done in SQL.

And remember: *disk space is for free*. It is very easy to have an XXX GB cache on disk, and effectively using only XXX MB of it. The *hard hitters* will be in memory while the *long tail* will sit on disk. And it is always possible to grow or shrink the cache.

Cost estimate for the uncached version:

- I/O + buffer memory cost for 2 files
- CPU + memory cost for the diff operation
- buffer memory for the result.

Cost estimate for the cached version:

- I/O + to fetch the diff
- CPU + memory for the query
- buffer memory for the result

If you compare the two:

- the uncached version has a larger I/O cost (given the diff is smaller than the sum of the two files)
- The uncached version always has a larger memory footprint
- The query cost could be smaller than diff-execution cost. Or it could be larger...